# Searching array elements in app engine entity

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an array - Books, with names of books in it.
In the google app engine, I already have a database of books stored in entities. Now I want to find which of the books in the array are there in the database stored in app engine. Can someone please let me know how to proceed using JAVA?

Answer (score 1):

Not really the place to get others to write your code for you, when it comes to fundamental programming.  There is no shame in being a beginner.  We've all been there, and welcome to programming.  But for fundamentals, your really should check the online tutorials and readily available docs.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html